# Is it possible to affix a file extension to php $SESSION files?

Tags: php, session, file-extension

While I was customizing my php.ini file as to SESSION, I didn't see anything relevant, and searches on the subject have not turned up anything relevant.

The SESSION data is being reliable stored, and can be modified, no problems with the SESSION itself.  But there is an annoyance in that every time I wish to view the data, Windows complains that it cannot open file of unknown type... selecting NotePad2 via that dialogue box all the time could be avoided if I were able to name the SESSION files.  To add for instance  "    .txt "

Example As IS :
sess_LIH7by43o4ufbql3rvERvp9vho8uHp9u3l4jnpw93rhlkrjdnvv98y29o8u3hvpo8w734h

What I would like:
sess_LIH7by43o4ufbql3rvERvp9vho8uHp9u3l4jnpw93rhlkrjdnvv98y29o8u3hvpo8w734h.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't modify the session filenames.

Instead, try simply having your text editor open, and dragging the files into the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set a permanent open type with `Notepad ++` ?

**Right click** the **`SESSION`** token and choose, Open with -> Notepad++ , and Select the below checkbox where it  says

"`Always use the selected program to open this kind of file`".

Click **OK**.

**EDIT**

> That was the first thing tried, but the option "Always use the
>   select/..." stays greyed out in the dialogue box. Because reasons. And
>   it is Windows.

- Open Control Panel / Default Programs.
- Select the Associate a file type or protocol with a program link.
- After all of the file types load, select the file type you wish to configure and click the Change Program button.
- If the program is not in the Recommended section, click the down arrow for Other Programs.
- If it is still not visible, select the Browse button and navigate to where the programs *.EXE file is located.
- Select the program and click OK.

### If that doesn't work, Here's a thread from [`SuperUser`](https://superuser.com/questions/153465/always-use-this-program-to-open-these-files-is-grayed-out-why)

Comment: That was the first thing tried, but the option "Always use the select/..." stays greyed out in the dialogue box.  Because reasons.  And it is Windows.

Comment: Updated a fix for that.

Comment: That SuperUser link looks promising if one trusted Windows not to just break half a dozen other things along the way.  I trust someone will find it helpful though. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this, but if it is vitally important to have a file extension, you could write your own session handler that saves the sessions in whatever filename format you like.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php